# Tabs performance like windows office tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs

I want the tabs performance on a web page to work like in widows office tabs.

[image]

Like in this image "AutoCorrect" is current tab, if we click on "Smart Tags" the top rows goes down like below.

[image]

Is there any solution for tab row interchange using jQuery? Tab rows can be more.

Please help.